# Rails validation on custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know you can do:

```
validates :cat_no, :presence => true, :on => :create
```

I have a custom action:

```
 def approve
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.update_attribute :approved, true
    redirect_to product_path(@product)
 end
```

And i'd like to do:

```
validates :cat_no, :presence => true, :on => :approve
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the idea of validations. Validations are triggered by changes to the *model* (via `save`, `create` or `update`), not by controller actions, so it doesn't make sense in your case to have your `approved` action trigger a validation.

Looking at your code, it seems to me what you really want to do is run a validation on `cat_no` when the model is *updated*, on the condition that the value of `approved` has just become `true` (i.e. line 2 of your `approve` action where you have `@product.update_attribute :approved, true`).

I think the code below should achieve that:

```
validates :cat_no, :presence => true, :on => :update, :if => :just_approved?

def just_approved?
  changed.include?("approved") && approved?
end
```

UPDATE:

In retrospect, the validation above is probably more permissive than what you'd actually want to have. If you have an approved record and you change `cat_no` to `nil`, it will validate because `approved` has not changed (so `changed.include?("approved")` will evaluate to `false`).

More likely this is what you actually want:

```
validates :cat_no, :presence => true, :on => :update, :if => :approved?
```

Comment: Ah, this make more sense now. I'll try your suggested code now. many thanks

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work. It's still letting me set approved to true on a product that's missing a cat_no

Comment: I've tested similar code and it works for me, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Try taking off the `:if` conditional first as a sanity check, to make sure it runs the validation, and if that's working then put back the `:if` conditional and try removing the `changed.include?("approved")` half of `just_approved?` (which will then also run the validation in the case where the value of `approved` was already `true`).

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation to my answer.

Comment: This is close but it's not quite right. Validation is triggered on update on my main form when a product is approved, but not on the custom action (that I assume is also triggering an update on the model). I do however only want to set approved to true when it meets the validations i've put in place. I guess it's an unconventional approach, but instead of validating on user input, we only want to validate when approve is clicked. This allows our users to 'flesh out' and build their products even if they only have partial info initially.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15149/discussion-between-shioyama-and-ryan-berry)

Answer (score 1):

The :action option specified in the validates statement is not a controller action but an action on the model itself, that's the reason that approve action of the controller does not trigger the validation of the model.

What you should do in your case is to remove the :on option of your validate statement:

```
validates :cat_no, :presence => true
```

Now the model will validate cat_no is present each time it is being saved.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not clear, it seems you are trying to use Active Record validations in your controller which should not be the case. You can use ActionController filters instead which is easy to do:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :cat_no, :only => :approve

  def approve
    # your approve action code goes here.
  end

  private
  def cat_no
    #implement your 'validation' here.
  end

end
```

Take a look at the [ActionController Filters guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
validates_presence_of :cat_no, on: :approve

def approve
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.attributes = product_params
  @product.save(context: :approve)
  redirect_to @product
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :cat_no)
end
```